# Deploying pyqt application to Windows using pyqtdeploy

Tags: qt, deployment, pyqt, qmake, pyqt5

I would like to deploy for the first time my first app made with PyQt5. I found `pyqtdeploy` ([link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/introduction.html)) to be probably what I need to do this for Windows and other platforms.

Anyway, I am following [this tutorial](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/tutorial.html), but, as I am completely new to deploying applications, I am not sure on one thing: do I need to download Qt for the target specific platform I need to deploy my app to? If so, am I supposed to use `qmake` from that Qt installation against the result of `pyqtdeploy`? For example: if I want to deploy to Windows, do I have to download Qt from [here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) (and which version???)?

From the same tutorial page, this is not so clear, maybe it's obvious, but as I am a newbie in this, not for me.

Comment: Have you looked at [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)? pyqtdeploy seems needlessly complicated to me...

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using it in the end. It seems a great and simple tool for my aim, and it also has a quite good documentation.

Answer (score 2):

**No you don't need to download Qt.
When building your 'sysroot.toml' file, pyqtdeploy will download qt-everywhere-src and builds it from source.**

In the built sysroot directory you can find qmake executable in *"...\Qt\bin"* (qmake.exe) depends on where your project files (sysroot.toml file) are.

For example if your host machine is Windows and `C:\Users\username\Desktop\My_PyQtDeploy_Proj` is your project folder which contains sysroot.toml, after building sysroot you can find qmake in `"C:\Users\username\Desktop\My_PyQtDeploy_Proj\sysroot-win-64\Qt\bin\qmake.exe"`

Comment: 5 years later I thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I am not able to test it anymore as I am not working on this topic. I give you a +1 because I bet this would have solved my problem though ;)